# Label parts (with Callout) in AnatomyPlot3D

Tags: labeling, anatomyplot3d, labelling

I would like to label or Callout individual anatomy components in an AnatomyPlot3D, all visible at the same time.

Here is what *doesn't* work:

```
AnatomyPlot3D[
 Callout[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Head"], "the head"],
 ViewPoint -> Left]
```

Comment: `AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Head"],  ViewPoint -> Left]` already delivers a plot with callouts. Simply hoover with the mouse over a specific part.

Comment: Ahhh... thanks... but I should have said I want the Callouts to be "permanent" and all visible at the same time... much like on static graphs.

Comment: On the doc [page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnatomyPlot3D.html) look under `Applications`. There is an example application called `anatomyCallouts`.

Comment: Yep... that works.  Thanks so much!